# How to change all the language of Google speech recognition?

Tags: python

**Audio_text_from_wav_file = r.recognize_google(audio)**

The above line reads only english language but,
If I use:

**Audio_text_from_wav_file = r.recognize_google(audio, language ="ru-RU")**

My .wav file reads only russian language. How can I able to read all the langauges from gtts or googletrans python.

I used libraries such as:

```
import speech_recognition as sr 
from googletrans import Translator 
from gtts import gTTS 
import os
```

I found a solution that I mentioned above but I can't change the code every single time in order to read different language from .wav file and translate it. I don't want to use any API's.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could create a list with all the target languages you want to try, and use a for loop to iterate over that list of target languages:

```
import speech_recognition as sr 
from googletrans import Translator 
from gtts import gTTS 
import os

# Set the list of target languages you want here
targetLanguages = ["en-GB", "ru-RU", "fr-FR"]

for eachLanguage in targetLanguages:
    Audio_text_from_wav_file = r.recognize_google(audio, language = eachLanguage)
```

A full list of all the language codes can be found in the web page below:

https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/languages

Comment: Thanks for Solution Still not working.

I used 10 languages and used the above code still doesn't read proper language.